# initialize member function from function pointer

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

i don't know how to initialize a member function from function pointer passed on constructor .. 
my class have a member function RHS that change in function of the differential problems .. so I need to pass a function in the constructor !
what is the right way ?

```
class RhsOdeProblem 
{
    public:      
      // constructor without alalitical solution
     constexpr  RhsOdeProblem (double (*rhs)(double, double),
                               double, double, double, double ) noexcept ;    


     virtual ~RhsOdeProblem() noexcept = default ;
     RhsOdeProblem(const RhsOdeProblem& ) noexcept = default; 
     RhsOdeProblem(RhsOdeProblem&& ) noexcept = default ;



     double RHS(double, double); 
     double AnaSol();

     double dxdt(double, double);                   

     void setRhs(double (*rhs)(double, double)); 
     void setAnaliticalSolution( double (*realSol)(double,double));      

     double startTime ;
     double endTime   ;
     double dt        ;
     double initValue ;
     constexpr static double eps = 10e-8 ;   
     bool analiticalSolution ;  
};

constexpr RhsOdeProblem::RhsOdeProblem (double (*rhs)(double, double),
                                        double ti,
                                        double tf,
                                        double dt, 
                                        double y0 ) noexcept : startTime{ti}, endTime{tf},
                                                      dt{dt} , initValue{y0} ,
                                                      analiticalSolution{false}      
{                       
      setRhs(rhs);
}
```

how I can define setRhs ?? or which is the best way to doing so ?
thanks in advance

Comment: You can't set a member function-post fact. At the most you can have `RHS` be a regular function pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function pointers are the "C" way of doing things. Here, you can make the RHS  a function pointer as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46998349/4646394) answer or you can do it the "C++" way by using `std::function` like:

```
#include <functional>
class RhsOdeProblem 
{
     // ...
     std::function<double(double,double)> RHS;
     //...
};
```

and intialize in the constructor itself:

```
constexpr RhsOdeProblem::RhsOdeProblem (std::function<double(double,double)> rhs,
                                    double ti,
                                    double tf,
                                    double dt, 
                                    double y0 ) noexcept : startTime{ti}, endTime{tf},
                                                  dt{dt} , initValue{y0} ,
                                                      analiticalSolution{false},
RHS{rhs}      
{   }
```

or you can do it inside `setRhs()` :

```
void RhsOdeProblem::setRhs(std::function<double(double,double)> rhs) {
    RHS = rhs;
}
```

why `std::function` you may ask, because `std::function` is a more generic way of doing it (it accepts function pointers, lambdas, classes with overloaded `operator()` and you can also create `std::function` from `std::bind`).

But, `std::function` might generate a slightly bigger byte-code than function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a (member) function. A function is not a mutable thing in C++.

Fortunately you don't have to; you can simply define `RHS` to be a function pointer:

```
class RhsOdeProblem 
{
     // ...
     double (*RHS)(double, double);
     void setRhs(double (*rhs)(double, double));
};

void RhsOdeProblem::setRhs(double (*rhs)(double, double)) {
    RHS = rhs;
}
```

and later on call it like this:

```
double result = RHS(x, y);
```